AWS Pinpoint - Multivariate and Yes/No split from custom channel response
I have setup a Pinpoint journey which calls a custom channel lambda function, this function calls a third party API and returns data in the format as below.
{ 
    <Endpoint ID 1>:{
        EventAttributes: {
            <Key1>: <Value1>,
            <Key2>: <Value2>, 
            ...
        } 
    }, 
    <Endpoint ID 2>:{ 
        EventAttributes: {
            <Key1>: <Value1>,
            <Key2>: <Value2>, 
            ...
        } 
    }, 
... 
}

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/channels-custom.html#channels-custom-lambda-create
I have tried using string and boolean values but to no success. Here is the redacted return values for my code.
{
    "Endpoint_ID": {
        "EventAttributes": {
            "Key1": "Yes",
            "Key2": "No"
        }
    },
...
}

For whatever reason it's only going down the Else path for Key1 trying value "Yes", "No", Yes and No. Any help is appreciated!
